# Blazor app passes JWT with claims over to web api service, but it receives them under different long names

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I setup sing-up-sing-in user flow in B2C tenant with my Blazor app with help of Msal, based on the latest .NET 8 libs like this

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    // for api call
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scope"]!);        
})
```

[image]

it works fine and among other claims returns Display name of a user inside `User` claim

so that `@context.User.Identity?.Name` (@context is `AuthenticationState` here) returns expected user's display name (coz NameClaimType is righty set to the "name" value like on the screenshot downbelow).

Blazor app also uses `AuthorizationMessageHandler` attached to http client to pass authorization token over to web api with each call.

Web api app requires authorization. I registered another web api application in B2C, created a scope, and added permission to it from the registered Blazor app. There is nothing unique in the flow, it's classical as could be seen on multiple Azure B2C Blazor -> web app youtube videos.

The interesting part that I do not get is why web api receives same 16 claims as Blazor does, but sometimes under different names and with a wrong NameClaimType like shown on the picture below (left is Identity in Blazor, right is how Identity object is filled for Web api

[image]

Name is null since `NameClaimType` is set to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name` which is not even in the list of the claims.

On the web service name I use

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
...
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I wonder why web api receives some claims under different names (e.g. long `htpp://shemas.../objectidentifier` in web api vs short `oid` in Blazor) and why `NameClaimType` is wrongly set in web api

Comment: well Balzor uses `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames` naming space, while Web Api uses `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes`, still not sure why they use different sets, probably relying on different defaults. I know I can redefine them